# Next semantic version php

Tags: php, laravel, string, semantic-versioning

Hi I would like to update a semantic version number using php for a three digit system  in string form.
An example :

```js
'1.0.0' => function => '1.0.1'
'1.0.12' => function => '1.0.13'
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Will this just be for the next **patch** version? Are you able to provide a little more context? Is there anything you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers you want for the semantic-versioning is you can get in,

[PHLAK/SemVer](https://github.com/PHLAK/SemVer)

Composer also have the library for the same but the methods are easy from SemVer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code snippet for this:

```
    $parts = \explode('.', $previousTag, 3);
    $newTag = $parts[0] . '.' . $parts[1] . '.' . (++$parts[2]);
```

Ignoring here edge cases for alpha, beta, rc, ... releases.